# Error trying to compile program from instructor (symbols expected in define line)

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors

I was given a template from my instructor and then modified the code to frequency histogram of a given text. However i'm getting errors trying to compile the code. I believe the errors indicated by the compiler is at the beginning of the code. The errors have been taken a screenshot of and attached below. Thanks in advance

errors:

```
test.c:6:25: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '\x20'
 #define FIRST_PRINTABLE ' '  // Space character code 32, see Etter 2016 text, pp. 418-420
                         ^
test.c:8:30: note: in expansion of macro 'FIRST_PRINTABLE'
 #define NUM_PRINTABLE (int) (FIRST_PRINTABLE-LAST_PRINTABLE+1)
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:11:38: note: in expansion of macro 'NUM_PRINTABLE'
 void init_array(int histogram[], int NUM_PRINTABLE);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

code:

```
/*
 *  Comp120 - Lab 7:  Starter project -- Complete this code
 *  Character Frequency analysis -- read a text file and display frequency 
 *  analysis
 *     for all printable characters.
 *
 *  Author: J. Fall
 *  Date: Feb. 2017
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdbool.h>

// Definition of printable character set 
#define FIRST_PRINTABLE ' '  // Space character code 32, see Etter 2016 text, pp. 418-420
#define LAST_PRINTABLE '~'
#define NUM_PRINTABLE (int) (FIRST_PRINTABLE-LAST_PRINTABLE+1)

// Function prototypes:
void init_array(int histogram[], int NUM_PRINTABLE);
int sum_array(const int histogram[], int NUM_PRINTABLE);
bool isPrintable(char c);
void compute_frequency(char* filename, int histogram[], int NUM_PRINTABLE);
void write_histogram(int histogram[], int NUM_PRINTABLE);
FILE* openFileRead(char* filename);

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   if (argc < 2) {
      printf("Usage: freq inputFile \n");
      exit(-1);
   }

   int histogram[NUM_PRINTABLE];  // Array of counters -- one for each printible character

   compute_frequency(argv[1], histogram, NUM_PRINTABLE);

   write_histogram(histogram, NUM_PRINTABLE);

   printf( "Program complete. \n" );

   return 0                           ;
}

/*
 * Initialize the array of integers of given length to all zeros
 */
void init_array(int histogram[], int NUM_PRINTABLE) 
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<NUM_PRINTABLE;i++){
        histogram[i]=0;
    }  // TODO: write function to assign 0 too every array element.
}

/*
 * Return the sum of all items in the given array
 */
int sum_array(const int array[], int NUM_PRINTABLE)
{
   int i = 0;
   int sum = 0;
   for(i=0;i<NUM_PRINTABLE;i++){
       sum = sum + histogram[i];
   }
   return sum; // TODO: write function to add up every element in the given array.
}

/*
 * Return true iff the character is PRINTABLE
 */
bool isPrintable(char c)
{
   if (c >= FIRST_PRINTABLE && <= LAST_PRINTABLE){
       return true;
   }
   else
       return false;  // TODO:  write function to return true iff c is a printable character
}

/*
 * Compute the frequency histogram for all PRINTABLE characters in the given file
 */
void compute_frequency(char* filename, int histogram[], int NUM_PRINTABLE)
{
   FILE* inputFile = openFileRead(filename);

   init_array(histogram, NUM_PRINTABLE);

   char c = getc(inputFile);  // priming read -- read first character from file
   while (c != EOF) {
      if(isPrintable(c)){
      int bin = c - FIRST_PRINTABLE;// TODO: write algorithm to count the number of times character c occurs.
      histogram[bin]++;
      }
      // HINT: since array indexes start at zero, map the ASCII code for each
      //       printable charcter onto an index by subtracting FIRST_PRINTABLE



      // After processing previous character, read next character from file to re-prime the loop
      c = getc(inputFile);   
   }
}

/*
 * Write the frequency histogram out to the given file
 */
void write_histogram(int histogram[], int NUM_PRINTABLE)
{
   FILE* outputFile = stdout;  // Simplifictaion:  output is written to the console instead of to an output file.

   int total_count = sum_array(histogram, NUM_PRINTABLE);
   fprintf(outputFile, "Frequency Analysis Results.  Input contained %d printable characters. \n", total_count);
   fprintf(outputFile, "Char | Frequency \n");
   fprintf(outputFile, "____ | _________ \n");
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<NUM_PRINTABLE; i++) {
      char ch = (char) (i + FIRST_PRINTABLE);
      double freq;
      if (histogram[i] > 0) {
         double freq = histogram[i]/(double)total_count * 100;
         fprintf(outputFile, "%3c  | %9.3f%% \n", ch, freq);
      }
      else
         fprintf(outputFile, "%3c  | %9d%% \n", ch, 0);
   }
}

/*
 * Attempt to open the file for read access.
 * Peforms error check and exits if file is not accessible
 */
FILE* openFileRead(char* filename)
{
   FILE* inFile = fopen(filename, "r" );
   if( inFile == NULL) {
      printf( "Error opening input file %s, program terminating!\n", filename);
      exit(-1);
   }
   return inFile;

}
```

Comment: `NUM_PRINTABLE` evaluates as a literal (or rather a computed constant). It cannot be used as a parameter name. what do you want to achieve?

Comment: also please post your errors _as text_. You could post the code as text, do the same for errors.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Well, it can be *passed* as an argument to the function at a call site. :P

Comment: replace all `int NUM_PRINTABLE` by `int num_printable` and at least it will compile

Comment: @StoryTeller Right!! I stand corrected

Comment: should i assign NUM_PRINTABLE to length like : int length = NUM_PRINTABLE instead? would that fix the issue? thanks

Comment: yes, that would do!

Answer (score 1):

```
#define NUM_PRINTABLE (int) (FIRST_PRINTABLE-LAST_PRINTABLE+1)

// Function prototypes:
void init_array(int histogram[], int NUM_PRINTABLE);
```

when those both lines are expanded by preprocessor it translates as (you can use `gcc -E` on the source to see it in action):

```
void init_array(int histogram[], int (int) (' '-'~'+1));
```

which is obviously a syntax error. Just use `NUM_PRINTABLE` as a constant in your functions, not as a parameter.

Aside, the macro is functionnaly wrong, it should be

```
#define NUM_PRINTABLE (LAST_PRINTABLE-FIRST_PRINTABLE+1)
```

or the value would be negative. (and you don't need to cast to `int` since character literals are already `int`)

Comment: I seem to have found the problem. Thankyou so much Jean! you rock

Comment: you're welcome. I think a lot of other people would have helped you if I didn't. BTW check my edit. here's how your question should look like (no images of text at all)